# How to Add ASIHTTPRequest to a running ASINetworkQueue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I have been trying to fire multiple download requests using ASIHTTP library. I am able to start the download for the 1st request... but when I add another ASIHTTPRequest to the queue, its not downloading.. Can you plz suggest anyway to make the next download start..

```
-(void)createNewDownloadRequestWithURL:(NSString *)videoURL andProgressIndicator:      (UIProgressView *)progressView andDelegate:(id)delegate
{
ASIHTTPRequest *request;
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
NSString * destFilePath = [[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Videos"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[videoURL lastPathComponent]];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:destFilePath];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.download",destFilePath]];
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[videoURL lastPathComponent],@"name",delegate,@"delegate",nil]];
request.delegate = self;
request.tag = VIDEO_DOWNLOAD_REQUEST;
[networkQueue addOperation:request];

if(!isDownloadOn)
    [networkQueue go];
isDownloadOn = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
[networkQueue go];
```

instead of:

```
if(!isDownloadOn)
    [networkQueue go];

isDownloadOn = YES;
```

You should invoke `[networkQueue go]` when you add a download request.

Comment: I did the same earlier... but non of my downloads start... 

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
search for add a request... to will a note in which its written networkQueue go need not to be called again and again